Keycloak + Apache containers timeout
I'm trying to start a container that contains apache and keycloak and configure the openoidc in it.
This is my docker-compose:
version: "3.8"

services:
  
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    expose:
      - "4200"
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    environment: 
      - KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak:8080
      - KEYCLOAK_REALM=master
      - KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=frontend
    depends_on:
      - keycloak

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.2
    container_name: keycloak
    expose:
      - "8080"
      - "9990"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    entrypoint: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  mockoon:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/module-federation-configuration/mockoon
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mockoon-one-container
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./infra/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

volumes:
  postgres:

And I'm having issues inside the apache to retrieve the openoidc configuration (everytime that the user try to enter to the server, this file is called), I'm receiving a timeout:
{ "type":"error", "host":"localhost", "timestamp":"2024-05-10 16:43:02.245778", "module": "auth_openidc:error", "pid": "1210", "thread_id": "275093427968", "source_file": " ", "client_ip": " 172.23.0.1:36164 ", "message": "oidc_util_http_call: curl_easy_perform() failed on: http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration (Connection timed out after 5002 milliseconds)", "referer": " " }
2024-05-10 17:43:02 { "type":"error", "host":"localhost", "timestamp":"2024-05-10 16:43:02.246884", "module": "auth_openidc:error", "pid": "1210", "thread_id": "275093427968", "source_file": " ", "client_ip": " 172.23.0.1:36164 ", "message": "oidc_provider_static_config: could not retrieve metadata from url: http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration", "referer": " " }

But the strange behavior is that if I try via terminal I can reach it:

Do you have any idea what can cause this issue?
I've tried to add a network but unfortunately there is no result. I don't know if it has any other option for that. Could it be some configuration inside httpd.conf?
